# es ist (durchaus) möglich?

Tags: word-usage

Is *es ist möglich, dass* not right?

If not, when do you use

> es ist möglich, dass

and when do you use

> es ist durchaus möglich, dass

Comment: The word `durchaus` emphazises that something is possible (möglich) => the probability is higher.

Comment: »Es ist möglich, dass das jemand für falsch hält« — what brings you to think that it could be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

> Es ist möglich, dass
>   It is possible, that

*Durchaus* increases the probability of something happening:

> Es ist **durchaus** möglich, dass
>   It is **very well** possible, that

Both are valid and are used often. Examples:

> Es ist möglich, dass es heute noch regnet.

If there is are signs that indicate a certain probability for it to rain you could say:

> Ist ist durchaus möglich, dass es heute noch regnet.

Answer (score 4):

Es ist möglich, dass: It is likely that

Es ist durchaus möglich, dass: It is quite likely that

So "durchaus" is powering the possibility.

Comment: *Likely* = wahrscheinlich. I'd recommend *possible* instead.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the German answer!

Der Ausdruck

> Es ist möglich, dass

sagt nichts über die Wahrscheinlichkeit aus, sie kann klein sein, sie kann groß sein.

Bei

> Es ist durchaus möglich, dass

würde ich nicht von Erhöhung der Wahrscheinlichkeit sprechen, vielmehr sehe ich das *»durchaus möglich«* als Ausdruck einer eher geringen Wahrscheinlichkeit im Sinne von *»mitnichten unmöglich [auch wenn viele es meinen], sondern – wenn alles zusammenkommt – möglich«*.